# Name for number of branches of a tree

Tags: trees

I'm working with trees in a project where I need to test various tree-making algorithms and their outcome. A frequent quantity I look for is the number of branches of a tree. Is there a commonly used name for that aside "number of branches"?

Comment: Can you define "number of branches"? Do you mean the *degree* of a node? The number of leaves in the tree? The number of edges in the tree?

Comment: That would be the number of leaves in the tree.

Comment: You can use *leaf number*.